# 7-segment decoder RBI/RBO pins

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, 7segmentdisplay

I know that RBO/RBI pins are used to blank leading zeros in a multi-digit display, but I've never used them once. How do they work? I mean If I ground an active low RBI pin, does that automatically blank out the output no matter what number it is displaying or only if the number displayed is zero? When will RBO be active, when output is zero or if RBI is active?

Comment: http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/using-seven-segment-displays-part-1  look at fig 18 near the bottom of the page

Comment: What does the data sheet say?